# Unreadable exception in ADO.Net/ASP.Net MVC has wrong encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, encoding, ado.net

Currently i have the problem, that thrown exception in an asp.net mvc applicaiton has a curious encoding and are not displayed correctly:

[image: SAException]

I've marked the curious parts with a yellow marker. Does i miss some encoding bugs?

**EDIT**

Visual Studio is saying similiar things. Every time i start the application, the message changes:

[image: VSEX]

Comment: Does the same weird error happen if you see the error in the debugger?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath added some more information to my post.

Comment: iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere is definitively NOT a .NET namespace. Either you are using an external library which has come corrupt, or you have some virus in your system. I'm inclined to believe it's the first, and that you should remove it.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath in another piece of code the assembly works just fine. Another thing is, every time i start the app, i get different exceptions.

Comment: I'm completely sure there's something wrong in that assembly. Delete it and downlad? it again

Comment: Already done. There must be some thing more woring. I now also get `Culture not supported exceptions`, `File not found exceptions` and `Access denied exceptions` for the asp.net temp folder. Every time i start the web site, i get another one. No idea why...

Comment: Look here on SO for ways to clear the ASP.NET cache, that might help